# Это я туплю или IDEA? Что здесь не так?

Tags: intellij-idea

Вот у меня пример для проверки работы конструкции if -- else if -- else : IDEA (2018.2.1 Community Edition) в 3 местах подчёркивает жёлтым и если соглашаться с её предложениями (Alt + Enter или "лампочка") то : 1. Вывод "А" вообще удаляет полностью, что неприемлимо 2. В оставшихся жёлтых местах начинает ходить по кругу со своими исправлениями Это я туплю или IDEA? Что здесь не так?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       int n = 4;

       if ( n == 1) {
           System.out.println("A");
       } else if ( n == 2) {
           System.out.println("B");
       } else if ( n == 3) {
           System.out.println("C");
       } else {
           System.out.println("D");
       }

   }
```

Comment: Наверное, она умная, и понимает, что вариант `n == 1` в этом коде не реализуется. Но глупая, потому что после первого исправления забывает свои предыдущие выводы...

Comment: Скорее всего IDE тупит, код рабочий, проверил у себя тоже в IDEA

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего IDE определяет, что `int n = 4;` задано вручную и не меняется, поэтому условные ветвления не имеют смысла

Answer (score 1):

IDEA видит явно заданную переменную и предупреждает, что в данном коде она всегда равна 4. именно поэтому она предлагает такие изменения. 
Это не критична и вас всего лишь предупреждают, что вывод будет постоянно один и тот же.  Вынесите код проверки в отдельную функцию и IDEA перестанет вас предупреждать.

Так же вместо такой громоздкой  конструкции **if else if** используйте **switch case**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        test(n);
    }

    public static void test(int n) {
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("A");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("B");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("C");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("D");
                break;
        }
    }
```